# How can we identify whether a program is Mainframe zIIP eligible or not?

Tags: mainframe, processor

How can we identify whether a program can be executed on Mainframe zIIP engine or not ?
Can someone share sample zIIP eligible code ?

Comment: What is "zIIP eligible"?  Are you asking what kinds of programs can run in z/OS?  It would seem that this is specialized enough that you (or your team) should have experience already, and not something you could just randomly start working in.  Ultimately, this isn't a good question for this site.

Comment: @claises Try thinking of the mainframe as a off the shelf network and zIIP as one of the servers in the network. More technically  as well as normal cpu's a **mainframe** can have several [specialty engines](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSB27U_7.1.0/com.ibm.zvm.v710.hcpa7/speceng.htm) (like zIIP) that are dedicated to special tasks. These *specialty engines* are a lot cheaper than normal processors but are dedicated to specific tasks. zIIP runs data access (DB2 etc) tasks.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean?   Are you trying to understand if a program is already prepared to run on a zIIP or how to write code that can run on a zIIP or something else.

Comment: @Hogstrom --> I am trying to understand how to write code/modify existing one so that it can run on zIIP Processor.

Answer (score 1):

I think main points are that 1) IBM makes workload eligible to run as zIIP or not (like any Java is zIIP'able) and 2) it must be dispatched as [SRB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_Request_Block), not as [TCB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_Control_Block).

Look online. This is a popular subject. Like [this article by Jim Dee](https://www.bmc.com/blogs/ibms-ziip-for-mainframe-explained/). It even has hypothetical code scenario of what it takes to move workload from GP to zIIP.

If you need some other examples of zIIP code, consider any Java or zCX (Docker) workloads. They are probably running on zIIP.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is you can't tell if software is zIIP enabled by inspecting the code or looking for a flag.

Longer answer ...

Software that is zIIP eligible will certainly identify itself as zIIP eligible as its a selling point in the technical documentation or marketing information.

The way the question is phrased it sounds like you want to programmatically or using a tool tell if the software is zIIP-able.  There isn't really a way to check that as the software has to be setup to run as zIIP eligible.

Here is a good blog about [zIIPs from BMC](https://www.bmc.com/blogs/ibms-ziip-for-mainframe-explained/)

Google "zIIP eligible" and you'll find a lot of useful information.

Note that to be zIIP eligible is not simply a technical issue but also has license terms and conditions that impact software's ability to exploit the zIIPs.

From the BMC blog

> So why aren’t your mainframe vendors zIIP enabling all of the code in
> all their products? The answer gets back to the second restriction
> mentioned above – to be zIIP eligible, code must run under an SRB and
> therefore cannot invoke many z/OS services. Most existing product code
> was written to run in TCB mode. Historically, SRB mode code was used
> only where it was considered a cost effective way to do cross memory
> processing.